# Using the verb "pray" without a preposition

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, prepositions, objects, lyrics

I'm a non-native speaker who's writing lyrics for a song. The line I'm having difficulties with is as follows:

> Oh, how I would pray Emily to stay.

Is this alright, or could this be interpreted as grammatical in some sense? I know we would usually use a preposition there but I don't have room for another syllable. Changing the verb is also not an option, as I need the rhyme *stay/pray*.

Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: I pray you, don't worry about having a preposition. It's a bit more Shakespearean, but "I pray you" is essentially a flowery way of saying "please" and I think the line would work as written.

Comment: ... It can't, though, be considered as an equally idiomatic variant of 'How I would pray that Emily stayed'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for here I'm afraid is no.
In order to use *pray* in its archaic sense (as a call for action, or a request)

> Pray - a forceful way of saying "please"

Although I imagine someone somewhere has used the word in such a fashion, it sounds awful and I can find no documented use of it *without* a preposition or following verb.

Perhaps then you should
 [pray](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pray?q=Pray) for some inspiration...

Perhaps you could use one of the following words... (does it need to rhyme with stay?)

- *Oh, how I would beg Emily to stay*
- *Oh, how I'd plead with Emily to stay*
- *Oh, how I'd urge Emily to stay*

or perhaps a similar line...

- *Oh, how I wished Emily would stay*
- *Oh, how I prayed Emily would stay*